# Unable to run or reinstall or update yfinance

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda, yfinance

I have been using the package yfinance to retrieve stock prices for some time.  Recently, as noted in several online posts, the package stopped working due to an update to the package.  I thought that this would be a simple process to update the package and fix the problem.  This has not been the case.

I am using Anaconda so I want to update using `conda` instead of `pip` using PowerShell on a PC.

**What I have tried so far unsuccessfully**

```
$ conda update --all
$ conda update conda
$ conda update-c ranaroussi yfinance
```

None of these worked.  I tried to uninstall and then reinstall Anaconda then reinstall `yfinance`.  Yes, I agree that this seemed like overkill for what should have been a simple issue.  Unfortuntaelty, now I can't even install the package.  I am using the `conda` command that I originally used to install the package

```
$ conda install -c ranaroussi yfinance
```

, which comes from the developer's page.
[https://anaconda.org/ranaroussi/yfinance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1yMv.png)

Now, I try to run this I receive an error message that the package cannot be found in my current channels.
[Screenshot of error msg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1yMv.png)

At this point, I am just spinning my wheels and would appreciate some help.  I hope that someone who might have experienced a similar issue has a suggestion for how to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please copy+paste error messages, etc.; it's more readable and searchable by others

Comment: A link to the error message I received was included in the question.  The is included via the text "Screenshot of error msg."

Comment: I was not clear - I mean to ask that you copy error messages with text and do not use screenshots; Google won't parse a screenshot like it can parse an error message made up of text

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's hosted on `anaconda.org`, this package doesn't appear to be a conda package. Its page only lists PyPI source and a one-liner to install with `pip`; i.e. compare [it](https://anaconda.org/ranaroussi/yfinance) to [a typical conda package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/numpy/files). Probably best here to just `pip install yfinance` into a conda environment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Using the pip approach through an Anaconda base(root) Terminal worked.